# How to apply status on a account that has its running total reaching zero

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Below is a sample data that i am trying to manipulate.

```
    +----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| ACCOUNT_NUMBER | TRANSACTION_DATE | bal     | Row# | RunningTotal | status      |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 155            | 31/03/2015       | 82.61   | 4    | 82.61        | CLEARED     |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 155            | 31/03/2015       | 85.25   | 5    | 167.86       | CLEARED     |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 155            | 31/03/2015       | 93.61   | 6    | 261.47       | CLEARED     |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 155            | 30/04/2015       | 78.95   | 7    | 340.42       | CLEARED     |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 155            | 22/05/2015       | -62.04  | 8    | 278.38       | CLEARED     |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 155            | 31/05/2015       | 98.95   | 9    | 377.33       | CLEARED     |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 155            | 30/06/2015       | 79.5    | 10   | 456.83       | CLEARED     |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 155            | 15/07/2015       | -345.76 | 11   | 111.07       | CLEARED     |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 155            | 12/05/2016       | -111.07 | 12   | 0            | CLEARED     |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 953            | 31/03/2015       | 2.5     | 13   | 2.5          | NOT_CLEARED |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 953            | 31/03/2015       | 2.5     | 14   | 5            | NOT_CLEARED |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 953            | 31/03/2015       | 2.5     | 15   | 7.5          | NOT_CLEARED |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 953            | 30/04/2015       | 2.5     | 16   | 10           | NOT_CLEARED |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 953            | 31/05/2015       | 2.5     | 17   | 12.5         | NOT_CLEARED |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 953            | 30/06/2015       | 0.67    | 18   | 13.17        | NOT_CLEARED |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 953            | 30/07/2015       | -0.81   | 19   | 12.36        | NOT_CLEARED |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 953            | 31/05/2018       | 5.08    | 20   | 17.44        | NOT_CLEARED |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 953            | 30/11/2018       | 1.02    | 21   | 18.46        | NOT_CLEARED |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 953            | 31/05/2019       | 1.48    | 22   | 19.94        | NOT_CLEARED |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 961            | 31/03/2015       | 8.38    | 23   | 8.38         | NOT_CLEARED |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 961            | 31/03/2015       | 10.65   | 24   | 19.03        | NOT_CLEARED |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 961            | 31/03/2015       | 25.07   | 25   | 44.1         | NOT_CLEARED |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 961            | 30/04/2015       | 12.21   | 26   | 56.31        | NOT_CLEARED |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 961            | 30/04/2015       | -20     | 27   | 36.31        | NOT_CLEARED |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 961            | 20/05/2015       | -36.31  | 28   | 0            | CLEARED     |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 961            | 31/05/2015       | -3.69   | 29   | -3.69        | NOT_CLEARED |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 961            | 31/05/2015       | 13.17   | 30   | 9.48         | NOT_CLEARED |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 961            | 30/06/2015       | 9       | 31   | 18.48        | NOT_CLEARED |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 961            | 25/07/2015       | -18.48  | 32   | 0            | CLEARED
```

Below is the script used to apply the status of the invoices. Essentially i want to be able to determine if a certain account has knocked off all its invoices. I have two conditions :

1. IF SUM of the balance equals zero then apply CLEARED
2. Second option which is what i am trying to figure out is to say. If somehow the final sum of the Running total isnt zero, but at the point where it clears let all the above invoices have cleared marker.

---

---

```
  select *,
    (CASE WHEN sum(bal) OVER (PARTITION BY ACCOUNT_NUMBER ) = 0 THEN 'CLEARED'
     WHEN sum(bal) OVER (PARTITION BY ACCOUNT_NUMBER order by Row#,TRANSACTION_DATE ) = 0 THEN 'CLEARED'
    else 'NOT_CLEARED'
    end) as status
     from #running_totals
    order by Row#, TRANSACTION_DATE
```

Can some assist me on how to apply this
Expected Results

```
   +----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| ACCOUNT_NUMBER | TRANSACTION_DATE | bal     | Row# | RunningTotal | status      |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 155            | 31/03/2015       | 82.61   | 4    | 82.61        | CLEARED     |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 155            | 31/03/2015       | 85.25   | 5    | 167.86       | CLEARED     |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 155            | 31/03/2015       | 93.61   | 6    | 261.47       | CLEARED     |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 155            | 30/04/2015       | 78.95   | 7    | 340.42       | CLEARED     |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 155            | 22/05/2015       | -62.04  | 8    | 278.38       | CLEARED     |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 155            | 31/05/2015       | 98.95   | 9    | 377.33       | CLEARED     |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 155            | 30/06/2015       | 79.5    | 10   | 456.83       | CLEARED     |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 155            | 15/07/2015       | -345.76 | 11   | 111.07       | CLEARED     |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 155            | 12/05/2016       | -111.07 | 12   | 0            | CLEARED     |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 953            | 31/03/2015       | 2.5     | 13   | 2.5          | NOT_CLEARED |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 953            | 31/03/2015       | 2.5     | 14   | 5            | NOT_CLEARED |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 953            | 31/03/2015       | 2.5     | 15   | 7.5          | NOT_CLEARED |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 953            | 30/04/2015       | 2.5     | 16   | 10           | NOT_CLEARED |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 953            | 31/05/2015       | 2.5     | 17   | 12.5         | NOT_CLEARED |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 953            | 30/06/2015       | 0.67    | 18   | 13.17        | NOT_CLEARED |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 953            | 30/07/2015       | -0.81   | 19   | 12.36        | NOT_CLEARED |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 953            | 31/05/2018       | 5.08    | 20   | 17.44        | NOT_CLEARED |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 953            | 30/11/2018       | 1.02    | 21   | 18.46        | NOT_CLEARED |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 953            | 31/05/2019       | 1.48    | 22   | 19.94        | NOT_CLEARED |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 961            | 31/03/2015       | 8.38    | 23   | 8.38         | CLEARED     |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 961            | 31/03/2015       | 10.65   | 24   | 19.03        | CLEARED     |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 961            | 31/03/2015       | 25.07   | 25   | 44.1         | CLEARED     |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 961            | 30/04/2015       | 12.21   | 26   | 56.31        | CLEARED     |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 961            | 30/04/2015       | -20     | 27   | 36.31        | CLEARED     |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 961            | 20/05/2015       | -36.31  | 28   | 0            | CLEARED     |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 961            | 31/05/2015       | -3.69   | 29   | -3.69        | CLEARED     |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 961            | 31/05/2015       | 13.17   | 30   | 9.48         | CLEARED     |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 961            | 30/06/2015       | 9       | 31   | 18.48        | CLEARED     |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
| 961            | 25/07/2015       | -18.48  | 32   | 0            | CLEARED     |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
|                |                  |         |      |              |             |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
|                |                  |         |      |              |             |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
|                |                  |         |      |              |             |  |  |
+----------------+------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------+--+--+
```

Comment: *"If somehow the final sum of the Running total isnt zero, but at the point where it clears let all the above invoices have cleared marker."* I don't follow what you're trying to say there. Expected results and further explanation(s) will help us help you.

Comment: Where is DT_Amount in your sample data?

Comment: Hi @mkRabbani edited to the correct bal, as in the table

Comment: Thanks for the expected results, but you haven't explained any further.

Comment: hi @Larnu lets say 961 its running total reaches zero, but has more uncleared invoices at the bottom of the point where it clears its invoices. all invoices above of the zero essentially should be cleared.

Comment: @omah94 please only keep columns that used in the query for sample data. And also just keep limited rows that covered your full scenario in sample and expected data. Unnecessary columns and extra rows creates confusion some time.

Comment: hi @mkRabbani thanks for the correction, i will sure leave most columns next time

Comment: @omah94 expecting some edit in your question for a better understanding :)

Comment: @mkRabbani addressed , guess you can now understand it better. Look at account_number 961. to get what i am trying ton say

Comment: Still I have doubt about your first couple of row as you set status to 'CLEARED'  with running total value > 0. Any way, I have added a query which may help you to get your desired result. You can check. @omah94

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197602/discussion-between-omah94-and-mkrabbani).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try.  Given the table of data you provided I would assume you will already have the RowNum row. You can probably improve on this, but it is a start.

```
;WITH CTE AS(
       select t1.ACCOUNT_NUMBER AN3, t1.RowNum RN3 
       from #temp  t1
       CROSS APPLY(select ACCOUNT_NUMBER AN2,RowNum RN2 
                from #temp where RunningTotal=0) t2 where t1.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = t2.AN2 and t1.RowNum <= t2.RN2
    )
    select ACCOUNT_NUMBER,TRANSACTION_DATE,bal,RowNum,RunningTotal,Status,
        CASE WHEN t2.AN3 IS NOT NULL THEN 'CLEARED'
            ELSE 'NOT CLEARED' END Status       
    from #temp t1
    LEFT JOIN CTE t2 on t1.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = t2.AN3 and t1.RowNum = t2.RN3
```

Comment: Hi @JM_ , thanks that did the trick. Just had to add distinct on the select after the CTE . to only return unique values.

Comment: @omah94 If this provided a solution I would please ask that you mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this following logic-

```
SELECT *,
    CASE 
        WHEN (SELECT MIN(ACCOUNT_NUMBER) FROM your_table) = ACCOUNT_NUMBER THEN 'CLEARED'
        -- I have considered the MIN ACC_NUMBER as per your data
        -- But you can also use a fix ACC_NUMBER if required like
        -- WHEN 199= ACCOUNT_NUMBER THEN 'CLEARED'
        WHEN            
            SUM(bal) OVER(
                PARTITION BY ACCOUNT_NUMBER ORDER BY ACCOUNT_NUMBER 
                ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
            ) = 0 THEN 'CLEARED'
        ELSE 'NOT_CLEARED'
    END Status
FROM your_table
```

Comment: Where is the mismatch?

Comment: for example i was expecting the first account number to have said everything is cleared. Since the account holder has paid off all their invoices

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this just by comparing the row number of the last row with status cleared and balance 0 to the last row with balance 0:

```
select rt.*,
       (case when sum(bal) over (partition by account_number) = 0
             then 'CLEARED'
             when max(case when status = 'CLEARED' and bal = 0 then Row# end) =
                  max(case when bal = 0 then Row# end)
             then 'CLEARED'
             else 'NOT_CLEARED'
        end) as status
from #running_totals rt
order by Row#, TRANSACTION_DATE
```